# How to align text and equation in two columns?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, vertical-alignment, alignment, text-manipulation

What I need to do is this:

[image]

I would like to have those two columns separated with the formulas aligned under.
The result I got is disappointing though. I altro tried with the align command but it doesn't work well.

How to properly do this?

Thank you!

Here the miserable code I tried:

```
\[\boxed{\qq{Simple Dispositions}} \qquad \qquad 
\boxed{\qq{Dispositions with Repetitions}}\]
\[ \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad 
\qquad  n^k\]
```

Comment: Is there something particular in that image that you are not happy with? Also, if you provide your code people will be more willing (and able) to help you.

Comment: Yes, I would like the formulas below to be centered with the text (aligned below in a "perfect" way). I am going to write down the code I used, but trust me: it's miserable and ridiculous...

Comment: Maybe try a tabular, with centered columns?

Comment: Sorry, your code doesn't/can't compile. Please make sure, a simple copy&compile is all we need to do to reproduce your .pdf, i.e. please save us from reengineering your code. Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO The possible "error" is the \qq command. You can replace \qq with \text, then it will compile for sure.

Comment: The error starts with a missing `\documentclass` ... followed by at least one missing package and so on ...

Comment: Probably the `tabular` will do but it's better if you show [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/why-does-tex-require-such-elaborate-mwes). Is the image a slide, s.a. beamer, or the part of an article? MWE would be something like this: ```\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your picture shows the equations as having the same baseline, i.e., the simple expression in the second column will align properly with the fraction line on the left.  "Easy" attempts with multiple columns will top-align the two equations.  Please be specific about which alignment you want.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a `tabularx` environment with a target width of `\textwidth` and two equal-width X-type columns with horizonally and vertically centered contents.

The framelines at the edges of the following screenshot are drawn because the test document loads the `showframe` package. You may omit doing this in your real document.

[image]

It's left to the user to assure that the boxes' contents don't exceed `0.5\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % horizontal centering
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % vertical centering

\usepackage{showframe} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\null % just for this example

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} CC @{}}
\fbox{Simple Dispositions} & \fbox{Dispositions with Repetitions} \\
\[ \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \] & \[ n^k \]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow amazing!! Going to study that environment!

Answer (score 1):

Please find attached two ways to do it:

- using Tikz and paracol (lets you switch columns)
- using tabular (similar to Mico's approach)

[image: results]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    frm/.style={draw},
    big/.style={font=\Large},
}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\section{A solution using tikz and paracol}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \tikz{
        \node[frm] at (0,0) {Simple Dispositions};
        \node[big] at (0,-1) {$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$};
    }
    \switchcolumn
    \tikz{
        \node[frm] at (0,0) {Dispositions with Repetitions};
        \node[] at (0,-1) {$n^k$};
    }
\end{paracol}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\section{A solution using tabular}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \fbox{Simple Dispositions} & \fbox{Dispositions with Repetitions}\\[5mm]
    $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ & $n^k$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**P.S.:** With Tikz it's simple to change colors, if you like:

```
    \switchcolumn
    \tikz{
        \node[frm,red] at (0,0) {Dispositions with Repetitions};
        \node[red] at (0,-1) {$n^k$};
    }
\end{paracol}
```

[image: red text etc]